# Estou a tentar duplicar as linhas com um For conforme o valor do stock

Tags: python, pandas, for, dataframe

Eu usei dois fores um para recolher o valor do stock em todas as linhas do dataframe e outro para duplicar cada linha por esse número.
Mas invés de duplicar todas as linhas por os seus respectivos números de stock está a repetir todas as linhas por o último número de stock da última linha.

```
valorrepetir = []

for index, row in tabela.iterrows():
   print(int(row['Quantidade Entrada']))
   valorrepetir.append(int(row['Quantidade Entrada']))

for i in valorrepetir:
    print(i)
    tabela_new = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(tabela.values, i, axis=0))
```

Estou a usar o código a cima, acho que o problema está na forma como eu crio a nova tabela no segundo for.
Alguém pode-me ajudar?!!

Answer (score -1):

já consegui mas não utilizei os for´s, fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
valorrepetir = tabela['Quantidade Entrada'].tolist()
tabela_new = tabela.loc[np.repeat(tabela.index.values, valorrepetir)]
```

Quem tiver o mesmo problema tem aqui um solução se quiser utilizar

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).